# Prevent SqlBulkCopy to change XML value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to transfer data from one database to another. My problem is that my XML column will be changed during the bulk copy.

I think that the SqlBulkCopy class is parsing/computing the XML and "simplify" the XML.

Original value:

```
<Item></Item>
```

Changed value:

```
<Item/>
```

This causes an error in my validation procedure, because the original XML is not the value which is stored in the target database.

Is there a way to prevent the `SqlBulkCopy` class to change my XML?
Because the SQL statement is generated before without knowing that there is an XML column, I also can not convert it to `nvarchar(max)`.

My code:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(source_command))
{
    using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
    {
        adapter.Fill(table);
        using (SqlConnection destination = new SqlConnection(destination_connectionstring))
        {
            destination.Open();

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destination, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, null))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destination_table;
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1200;

                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName));
                }

                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    table.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**It is important that the xml-string representation is the same in the origin and target database.**

Comment: Its still valid XML, representing exactly the same data, so you should change your validation to handle that

Comment: Of course it is, but the processing system assumes that it is exactly the same notation. A change in the validation process is not possible in this regard due to the limitation of the processing system. Unfortunately, I cannot ignore this requirement

Comment: `Unfortunately, I cannot ignore this requirement.` Unfortunately, `SqlBulkCopyOptions` doesn't have a `CaterForPoorlyWrittenProcessingSystemsThatTreatXmlAsText` flag. If you "cannot" change your validation procedure, and you "cannot" change your column datatype from `xml` to `nvarchar(max)`, then you cannot use `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in `table`, how are you passing it? You could maybe pass an `XmlDocument` with `PreserveWhitespace = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `SqlBulkCopy` class.

I solved my problem by adding a specific validation in the case the string-representation is not the same. If so I run a select on the sql server with an convert to XML.

Example:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(XML, '<test><item></item></test>'
```

then I get a result like this:

```
<test>
   <item/>
</test>
```

It is also possible to command the sql server to preserve whitespaces.
More to this problematic: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223496/sql-server-changes-xml-structure-when-inserted